# Android MapsApiV2 Location.distanceTo is giving wrong values

Tags: android, api, google-maps

**This seems like a duplicate question but it is not. Please read before you mark it as duplicate**

I was trying to get distance between two LatLng, so first i generated it's **PolylineOptions**, 

Now the problem is - The output is not understandable.

It's different from other questions because it uses PolylineOptions.

**Calculating Code**

```
@Override
public void onParserTaskComplete(PolylineOptions points, int count) {
    if (points != null) {
        float totalDistance = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < points.getPoints().size(); i++) {
            Location currLocation = new Location("this");
            currLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i).latitude);
            currLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i).longitude);

            Location lastLocation = new Location("this");
            currLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i - 1).latitude);
            currLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i - 1).longitude);

            totalDistance += lastLocation.distanceTo(currLocation);


        }
        items.get(count).setDistance(String.valueOf(totalDistance));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        items.get(count).setDistance("");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

According to Google Maps the distance should be around **5.5KM**
but output is coming like **8783711.0**

*Question -* How do i convert this value to KM?

Comment: check my answer, distance is ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You duplicated currLocation and don't set values for lastLocation.
This is correct way:

```
        Location currLocation = new Location("this");
        currLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i).latitude);
        currLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i).longitude);

        Location lastLocation = new Location("this");
        // here you used currLocation
        lastLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i - 1).latitude);
        lastLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i - 1).longitude);
```